# Natural Language Generation - how to test if it sounds natural

Tags: text, nlp

I just have a set of sentences, which I have generated based on painting analysis. However I need to test how natural they sound. Is there any api or application which does this?

I am using the [Standford Parser](http://nlp.stanford.edu:8080/parser/index.jsp) to give me a breakdown, but this doesn't exactly do the job I want!

Also can one test how similar sentences are? As I randomly generating parts of sentences and want to check the variety of the sentences produced.

Comment: I suppose reading them is out of the question?

Comment: @sudowned Well its not really very statistical is it! I need a method which produces results and doesn't really heavily on subjectivity

Comment: Try using Google's ngram data to check if strings exist. And for similarity, look into Dice's Coefficient or cosine similarity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A lot of NLP stuff works using things called ['Language Models'](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_model).

A language model is something that can take in some text and return a probability. This probability should typically be indicative of how "likely" the given text is.

You typically build a language model by taking a large chunk of text (which we call the "training corpus") and computing some statistics out of it (which represent your "model"), and then using those statistics to take in new, previously unseen sentences and returning probabilities for them.
You should probably google for "language models", "unigram models", "n-gram models" and click on some of the results to find some article or presentation which helps you understand the previous sentence. (Its hard for me to recommend an appropriate tutorial for you because I don't know what your existing background is)

Anyway, one way to think about language models is that they are systems that take in new text and tell you how similar the new text is to the training corpus the language model was made out of. So if you build 2 language models, one out of all the plays written by Shakespeare and another out of a large number of legal documents, then the second one should be giving you a much higher probability to sentences for some new legal document that just got released (as compared to the first model) while the first model should give you a much higher probability for some other old english play (written by some other author) because that play is probably more similar to Shakespeare (in terms of the kind of words used, sentence lengths, grammar, etc) than it is to modern legal language.

All the things you see the stanford parser give you back for a sentence you give it are generated using language models. One way to think about how those features are built is to pretend that the computer tried every possible combination of tags and every possible parse tree for the sentence you gave it, and used some clever language model to identify which is most probable sequence of tags and most probable parse tree out there, and returned those back to you.

Getting back to your problem, you need to build a language model out of what you consider natural sounding text and then use that language model to evaluate the sentences you want to measure the naturalness of. To do this, you will have to identify a good training corpus and decide on what type of language model you want to build.

If you can't think of anything better, a collection of wikipedia articles might serve to be a good training corpus representing what natural sounding english looks like.
As for model type, an "n-gram model" would probably be good enough for your task. More complicated models like "Hidden Markov Models" and "PCFG's" (the stuff that is powering the stanford page you linked to) would definitely make things even better, but n-grams are definitely the most simple thing you could start with.